# Retrieve URL / Request in a fail2ban action with nginx

Tags: nginx, fail2ban

I have configured fail2ban to block spam attempts with nginx. everything works but I would like to be able to retrieve the url / domain visited in my actions.
recovering the “logpath” also suits me because the latter is different for each vhost

Thanks

[jail conf](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LNef3.png)
[action conf](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AUBXE.png)
[error logs files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wkCsn.png)

I would just like to have the name of the site visited in the action.

thanks

Comment: Welcome to Server Fault! Please  use copy-paste and avoid posting screenshots of text when posting console output / settings. Format that text  as "`code`" using [Markdown](https://serverfault.com/editing-help) and/or the formatting options in the edit menu to properly type-set your posts. That improves readability, attracts better answers  and allows indexing by search engines, which may help people with similar questions. And that will allow people willing to answer your question to also copy-and-paste your commands/settings/error messages into their answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are only a handful of standard ***Action Tags*** available and as far as I know no other variables that you can use in `actionban`, `actionunban` and `actioncheck` so your options are limited:

> ## Action Tags
>
> The following tags are substituted in the actionban, actionunban and actioncheck (when called before actionban/actionunban)
> commands.
>
> - `ip` IPv4 IP address to be banned. e.g. 192.168.0.2
> - `failures` number of times the failure occurred in the log file. e.g. 3
> - `ipfailures` As per failures, but total of all failures for that ip address across all jails from the fail2ban persistent database.
>   Therefore the database must be set for this tag to function.
> - `ipjailfailures` As per ipfailures, but total based on the IPs failures for the current jail.
> - `time` UNIX (epoch) time of the ban. e.g. 1357508484
> - `matches` concatenated string of the log file lines of the matches that generated the ban. Many characters interpreted by shell get
>   escaped to prevent injection, nevertheless use with caution.
> - `ipmatches` As per matches, but includes all lines for the IP which are contained with the fail2ban persistent database. Therefore the
>   database must be set for this tag to function.
> - `ipjailmatches` As per ipmatches, but matches are limited for the IP and for the current jail.

Source: [`man jail.conf`](https://manpages.debian.org/testing/fail2ban/jail.conf.5.en.html#Action_Tags)

The `matches`  tag probably gives you more than you want or need, but might be the closest approximation of getting what you want.

As a work-around: rather than calling curl directly, you might want to have `banaction` call on a suitable custom script that extracts the details you want from the `matches` and then crafts a "better" `curl` request for you.